# emacs-style partial directory path completion in bash

Tags: linux, bash, bashrc

In emacs, when entering a file path, I can do something like:

```
~/c/s/h/npu2-o.c<TAB>
```

and have it expand to

```
~/code/skiboot/hw/npu2-opencapi.c
```

Is there any way to get similar path expansion in bash?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about bash, but at least Zsh can do that.  I haven't touched my Zsh completion config in a long while, so I'm not sure which part does that, but I think it's just `compinit`.  IIRC you can just run the `compinstall` command in Zsh and that will setup the completion config for you.

Answer (score -1):

Disclosure: I am the author of the project

This project enables the desired completion in bash: https://github.com/sio/bash-complete-partial-path

Hope you'll find it useful